# Is there any Linux intel display graphic driver for Toshiba Satellite C650 Laptop?

Tags: drivers, graphics, windows, display, intel

I tried many many Linux distros, but none of them runs as smoothly as Windows 7, 8.1, and 10. The animations on windows are very smooth but on Linux, it is really bad and that's the reason I'm unable to keep Linux as my daily driver. I wonder whether it is an issue with drivers or something else.

**Device Specifications:**
Processor:  Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU    P6100  @ 2.00GHz   2.00 GHz
Installed RAM:  4.00 GB
HDD: 500 GB

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar) . Your video is probably Intel iGPU, but GNOME Shell is to heavy for it. Try lighter alternatives like Ubuntu MATE or Lubuntu.